# Como puedo fusionar una imagen de fondo con un color en un layout ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un archivo xml donde desde otro xml le llamo y me pinta dos cuadrados donde los relleno de un texto. Ese cajetin tiene un color de fondo, pero mi idea es añadirle ademas una imagen de fondo y que se fusione con ese color

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/fondo1Positivo" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#282828" />
<corners android:radius="10dip" />
<padding
    android:left="0dip"
    android:top="0dip"
    android:right="0dip"
    android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Mi idea es hacer algo similar a esto:
[image: Planteamiento]
En esto:

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1):

La definición del color puedes usar el sistema `ARGB` (Alfa Rojo Verde Azul) con el canal alfa puedes establecer la opacidad del color.

`FF => 100%` y `00 => 0%`

la equivalencia de no establecer canal alfa es como si este al 100%

`282828 == FF282828`

Si le quieres dar un poco de transparencia prueba con `88......`

En tu caso particular quieres que el texto coge un poco de color dependiendo de atrás, pues el color del texto si le defines una pequeña transparencia ya dejará pasar ese % de color del fondo.

#### Fusionar dos imágenes del mismo tamaño

Se puede crear un recurso en drawable `fusion.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_overlay" />
</layer-list>
```

y usar como imagen resultante `@drawable/fusión`

**Otra manera**
Es usar un layout `FrameLayout` o `RelativeLayout` que puedes hasta posicionar la imagen sobreposada a donde quieras.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_blend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/watermark"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Las imágenes puedes definir si quieres que se puedan centrar, crop etc... [aquí la documentación de google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Perfecto cambiaré el código del color añadiéndole el canal alfa. Pero es que además de eso he añadido **android:background="@drawable/foto"** y ni si quiera me muestra la imagen. Que podré estar haciendo mal ? @Webserveis